# How can I login to Google with React Native and Firebase without using a popup?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

As I said, I want to login to my Google Account without having to create a popup, I mean keeping that Login Form with those inputs so the screen on the emulator won't be so empty. (sorry for the image looking like that, I do not know how to edit it in here.) [image]

I will copy and paste the code for the Firebase login:

```
  onButtonPress() {
    const {email, password} = this.state;

    this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
    .catch(() => {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
  })
}
```

But at the moment it is logging in with Email and Password and not with google.

I am trying to fetch the name of the user so that is why I want to login with google.

Answer (score 0):

This is a React part I did with Google Authentication. It's not tailored to your code but I thought it might help you get where you want to go!

```
class GoogleAuth extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.client
        .init({
          clientId:
            "65397550643-g040rl648ka1p4d0h0t58crsa5v8ni1a.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          scope: "email"
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
          this.onAuthChange(this.auth.isSignedIn.get());
          this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(this.onAuthChange);
        });
    });
  }

  onAuthChange = isSignedIn => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      this.props.signIn(this.auth.currentUser.get().getId());
    } else {
      this.props.signOut();
    }
  };

  onSignInClick = () => {
    this.auth.signIn();
  };

  onSignOutClick = () => {
    this.auth.signOut();
  };

  renderAuthButton = () => {
    if (this.props.isSignedIn === null) {
      return null;
    } else if (this.props.isSignedIn) {
      return (
        <button className="ui red google button" onClick={this.onSignOutClick}>
          <i className="google icon" />
          Sign Out
        </button>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <button className="ui green google button" onClick={this.onSignInClick}>
          <i className="google icon" />
          Sign in with Google
        </button>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="item">{this.renderAuthButton()}</div>;
  }
}
```